# Creating a width in time scale using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create bar chart with time as x axis..

My data:

```
var data = [
    {key: "Glazed", start:"2014/01/01", value: 92},
     ....// and so on
```

Here value is time in mins

For scaling I use:

```
var dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d").parse;
       var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.start);
            return date;
        }))
        .range([0,width]);
```

To get the x value in chart I use:

```
.attr("x",  function(d){
    var date = dateParser(d.start);
            return x(date);
        })
```

To get the width without scale I could use:

```
.attr("width", function(d){
       return d.value;
                })
```

I'm unable to figure out how to use width with scale in this case.

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is the width of the bar determined by a duration or something like that? What determines it?

Comment: width is determined by d.value which is in mins..

Comment: So you would add the minutes to the parsed date, pass that to the scale and subtract the scale value for the original date to get the width.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Tried unsuccessfully, an example code will be nice..tx

Comment: `x(dateParser(d.start) + d.value * 60 * 1000) - x(dateParser(d.start))`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Unfortunately does not work as + concatenates in js ;
x(dateParser(d.start) : 556.3636363636364;
d.value * 60 * 1000 :480000;

dateParser(d.start) + d.value * 60 * 1000: Fri Jan 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)480000;

x(dateParser(d.start) + d.value * 60 * 1000) : NaN

Comment: Ah right, just put a + in front of the date: `x(+dateParser(d.start) + d.value * 60 * 1000) - x(dateParser(d.start))`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Tx,This does create a width.. Could you please explain the change.. what is the difference when you add the + to dateParser

Comment: It converts it to a number.